# Qt5 add and remove widgets from my mainwindows

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.4

I have an ui app created in my QTCreator but I need remove a tablewidget that it have, in runtime.
Somebody can help me?
the code is it.

**MainWindows.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void eventos();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void exit();
    void aboutUA();
    void addCttoaction();
    void listCttoaction();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

MainWindows.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>671</width>
    <height>524</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>AU | Archivo Único</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>649</width>
      <height>459</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="dragEnabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="alternatingRowColors">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="sortingEnabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Salida</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>No. Contrato</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Destino</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Persona</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Tipo</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Entrada</string>
     </property>
    </column>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>671</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuArvhivo">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Archivo</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionSalir"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuAyuda">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Ayuda</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionSobre_AU"/>
    <addaction name="actionCr_ditos"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuContrato">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Editar</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionAdicionar_contrato"/>
    <addaction name="actionEditar_Contrato"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="actionSalida_de_Contrato"/>
    <addaction name="actionEntrada_de_contrato"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuListados">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Listados</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionListado_de_Contratos"/>
    <addaction name="actionContratos_Fuera"/>
    <addaction name="actionContratos_Originales"/>
    <addaction name="actionContratos_Copia"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuArvhivo"/>
   <addaction name="menuContrato"/>
   <addaction name="menuListados"/>
   <addaction name="menuAyuda"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionSalir">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Salir</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>Ctrl+Q</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSobre_AU">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Sobre AU</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionCr_ditos">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Créditos</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAdicionar_contrato">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Adicionar contrato</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSalida_de_Contrato">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Salida de Contrato</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionEntrada_de_contrato">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Entrada de contrato</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionListado_de_Contratos">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Listado de Contratos</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionContratos_Fuera">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Contratos Fuera</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionContratos_Originales">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Contratos Originales</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionContratos_Copia">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Contratos Copia</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionEditar_Contrato">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Editar Contrato</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I need delete this textfield but i don't know how can I do this with code in runtime because I need add another widget to my app in this mainwindows
Thanks

Comment: In your code i can't see the tableWidget you want to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete one of the UI objects (in this example, the `tableWidget`) with a simple `deleteLater()` invocation:

```
ui->tableWidget->deleteLater();
```

This will unbind all the signals and slots associated with it, and safely delete it.

However, you must be careful that you don't use it after you delete it--including calling `deleteLater()` *again* on it!  So you might consider:

```
if(ui->tableWidget)
    ui->tableWidget->deleteLater();
```

This use-after-free isn't an issue if you never explicitly use the `tableWidget` except via signals and slots, because QObject will safely disconnect everything when it's deleted.

Because of the above issue, I prefer to *hide* UI elements, rather than delete them.  To do this, simply call the `hide()` slot or `show(false) slot:

```
ui->tableWidget->hide();
```

The advantage is that everything remains connected, so you can re-show it later with `show()`.